# NSXMLParser don't get all the tag if the tag have accent

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a webservice with diferent changes for the DataBase. When I consume the webservice return lines with sql tags, like this:

```
<sql>
   DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ...
</sql>
<sql>
   INSERT INTO TABLE WHERE ...
</sql>
<sql>
   UPDATE TABLE SET ... WHERE ...
</sql>
```

I save this codes in the NSMutableArray like this:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName  {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"sql"]){
        [maResultado addObject:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ResultadoSoap]];
        [ResultadoSoap setString:@""];
    }
}
```

This is good, but if the webservice returns a word with an accent (accent because is in spanish), the app only get the phrase after the accent.
Example:
the web service return this:

```
<sql>
   INSERT INTO DATOS(datos, fecha) VALUES('Indagar si el médico a tenido oportunidad de ...', '20/02/2013')
</sql>
```

I do this:

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"sql"]){
    [maResultado addObject:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ResultadoSoap]];
    [ResultadoSoap setString:@""];
}
```

and in the maResultado in the objectatindex only have this:

```
édico a tenido oportunidad de ...', '20/02/2013')
```

Comment: Side note - please don't use `stringWithFormat:` unless you really have a string to format. This: `[maResultado addObject:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ResultadoSoap]];` should just be: `[maResultado addObject:ResultadoSoap];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parser:foundCharacters:` delegate function can be called more than once for an XML element. This happens in particular if the character content contains special characters. In your case, for the data

```
<sql>
   INSERT INTO DATOS(datos, fecha) VALUES('Indagar si el médico a tenido oportunidad de ...', '20/02/2013')
</sql>
```

the delegate function is called twice, first with the string

```
INSERT INTO DATOS(datos, fecha) VALUES('Indagar si el m
```

and then again with the string

```
édico a tenido oportunidad de ...', '20/02/2013')
```

Therefore, you have to *append* the string in `parser:foundCharacters:` to the current string, e.g.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}
```