# Error parsing XML encoding objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, afnetworking

I'm trying to parse an XML with AFXMLRequestOperation but the parsing stops when found the "ç" string, i dont know exactly how to parse this pice of string heres the code :

```
AFXMLRequestOperation * op = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:req success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser)
{
    NSLog(@"XML document %@", XMLParser);
    NSLog(@"response %@",response);

    XMLParser.delegate = self;
    [XMLParser parse];

}failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
    NSLog(@"response %@",response);
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}];


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{    
    NSString *correctString = [NSString stringWithCString:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"string %@",correctString);
}
```

and here is the XML :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><env:Header><wsa:MessageID>urn:E350F180FDEF11E2BF9C23C51C52395C</wsa:MessageID><wsa:ReplyTo><wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address><wsa:ReferenceParameters><instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">66a9395e96ada9e8:-78e4245e:1401282173b:-8000-0000000000210667</instra:tracking.ecid></wsa:ReferenceParameters></wsa:ReplyTo><wsa:FaultTo><wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address><wsa:ReferenceParameters><instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">66a9395e96ada9e8:-78e4245e:1401282173b:-8000-0000000000210667</instra:tracking.ecid></wsa:ReferenceParameters></wsa:FaultTo></env:Header><env:Body><TransactionResponse xmlns:aia="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.apps.aia.core.xpath.AIAFunctions" xmlns:ns0="http://www.site.com.br/" xmlns="http://www.site.com.br/"><ns0:Acquirer>ECOMMERCE</ns0:Acquirer><ns0:TransactionId>00</ns0:TransactionId><ns0:Complement>192071</ns0:Complement><ns0:AdditionalComplement>123456</ns0:AdditionalComplement><ns0:ResponseCode>00</ns0:ResponseCode><ns0:ResponseMessage>Transação Autorizada</ns0:ResponseMessage><ns0:TransactionStatus>PAGO</ns0:TransactionStatus><ns0:TransactionDate>2013-08-05T13:55:37.602-03:00</ns0:TransactionDate><ns0:OrderNumber>0000014</ns0:OrderNumber></TransactionResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSXMLParser don't get all the tag if the tag have accent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986699/nsxmlparser-dont-get-all-the-tag-if-the-tag-have-accent) - Short answer: you have to *append* the strings in `foundCharacters`.

Comment: Doesnt work @MartinR already tried this.

Comment: Does `parse` return NO? What is `parserError`? And why the encoding conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, This work for me.

```
const char *cc= [currentElementValue cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *d_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:cc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```