# Problems with NSXMLParser using single quotes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

It should store this string: **Jim's Random topic**. But it stops at the single quote. So it stores **Jim**.

< title >Jim&#039 ;s Random topic&#039 ;s about stupid semicolon&#039 ;s < /title>

**XMLParser.m** (Simplified)

```
typedef enum MESSAGE_TYPE {
    TITLE = 1,
    NOTFIRSTTIME = 2,
    SEMICOLON = 3
} Message_Type;

NSString * title;
NSXMLParser *rssParser;
Message_Type messageType;

+ (void)initialize {
     messageType = UNDEFINED;
}

- (void) parseXML:(NSData *) rawxml{

    NSString* myString;
    NSData *data;

    myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawxml encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    myString = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];
    [rssParser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        messageType = TITLE;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

if(messageType == SEMICOLON) {
    title = [title stringByAppendingString:string];
    messageType = NOTFIRSTTIME;
}

if(messageType == NOTFIRSTTIME) {
    if([string isEqualToString:@"'"]) {
        title = [title stringByAppendingString:string];
        messageType = SEMICOLON;
    }
}

    if(messageType == TITLE) {
        title = string;
        NSLog(@"title = %@",title);
        messageType = NOTFIRSTTIME;
    }
}
```

**Update:** I've solved my own problem with a loop that uses an Enum and appends the string when it finds a semicolon. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: check the nslog of **data**

Comment: have you access to change this <title> string…???

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986699/nsxmlparser-dont-get-all-the-tag-if-the-tag-have-accent . (foundCharacters: can be called more than once for an XML element.)

Comment: @MartinR it's kinda the same but didn't work for me because my XML has more different tags, I've added a "NOTFIRSTTIME" state to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's working now. I've updated the answer above.